# Разница между typedef и #define

Tags: c, c++

В чем состоит разница между `typedef` и `#define`?

Comment: Вопрос звучит как "В чем разница между бульдозером и гладиолусом?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Разница в том, что оператор `typedef` добавляет новое имя к уже существующим. Директива `#define` - это команда препроцессора. `typedef` поддерживается на уровне языка.

Answer (score 8):

`#define` - это директива автозамены. То есть он заменяет то, чем макрос именовали, тем, что в нём указали. И всё. Больше он ничего не делает. Другое дело, что таким образом объявленные макросы можно использовать в условиях, но это уже не по вопросу.

typedef - объявляет новый производный тип. И всё =)

Наглядное сравнение (простите за такое название, но наглядности ради):

```
#define macroint int *
typedef int * typedint;

macroint a, b; // превратится в такое: int * a, b;
typedint c, d;
```

При этом типы получаются:

```
a - int *
b - int (!!!)
c - typedint == int *
d - typedint == int *
```

Comment: `typedef` не объявляет *новый* тип. Он вводит *синоним* типа. Иначе можно было бы делать перегрузки по `typedef`, а это невозможно.

Answer (score 5):

`#define` - это директива препроцессора. Она позволяет объявить макрос, именованный фрагмент текста программы. И использовать идентификатор макроса в тексте программы, как будто это сам фрагмент. Поэтому директива `#define` служит для замены часто использующихся констант, ключевых слов, операторов или выражений некоторыми идентификаторами. typedef создает псевдоним(alias) для типа или функции.

Если использовать эти конструкции для замены вида int * на pint, то разница лишь в том, что typedef учитывает namespace, а #define всегда глобальны.

```
#define pchar char *

namespace t{
    typedef int * pint;
}

int main()
{
    pchar h; 
    t::pint g; 
    pint g2; // ошибка
    return 0;
}
```

Ну и еще с помощью `#define` можно делать гарантированные инлайн функции и работать с `#ifdef`

```
#define mul(x, y) ((x) * (y))
a = mul(5, 3 + 6); // будет заменено препроцессором на a = (5)*(3 + 6);

#define MY_DEBUG
...
#ifdef MY_DEBUG
// фрагмент будет скомпилирован, только если объявлен MY_DEBUG
MyMegaApp.doMoreChecks(); 
#endif
```

Можно наверно еще что-то добавить.

Comment: по поводу инлайновости:
<pre>#define mul(x, y) ((x) * (y))</pre>
возьмем такой пример
<pre>#define sqr(x) ((x) * (x))</pre>
А теперь используем в программе как
<pre>sqr(x++);</pre>
ну, было нам так удобно сделать :-) Итог? Абсолютно не ясно, что будет на выходе sqr :-) x увеличится не на 1, а на 2.
Так что макросы требуют очень внимательного отношения к себе и аккуратности в использовании.
Настоящая инлайновая функция таких побочных эффектов не имеет.

Answer (score 2):

#define объявляет макросы, подстановкой (в том числе рекурсивной) которых занимается препроцессор, а не компилятор. соответственно, никаких проверок и типа и тому подобной ереси, иногда бывает полезно.

Comment: В то время как все прогрессивное человечество приобщается к TypeScript, вы называете проверку типа ересью..